# How to convert a list to html <ul> using a for loop in django template

Tags: python, django, api

This is my first post, I am just getting started with python and django.  I have managed to successfully connect to a public (non authenticated) API. When I display the results - I can access all the fields however one of the fields is returned as a list - **Other roles**.  I can display the whole list (unformatted), comma separated - but I can't figure out how to iterate over the list and render it as an `<ul>`.

The returned list looks like this:

```
SOC: 3112 
Title: Electrical and electronics technicians 
Description: Electrical and electronics technicians perform a variety of miscellaneous technical support functions to assist with the design, development, installation, operation and maintenance of electrical and electronic systems. 
Qualifications: Entrants usually possess GCSEs/S grades, an Intermediate GNVQ/GSVQ Level II or a BTEC/ SQA award. NVQs/SVQs in Servicing Electronic Systems are available at Levels 2 and 3. 
Tasks: plans and prepares work and test schedules based on specifications and drawings; sets up equipment, undertakes tests, takes readings, performs calculations and records and interprets data; plans installation methods, checks completed installation for safety and controls or undertakes the initial running of the new electrical or electronic equipment or system; diagnoses and detects faults and implements procedures to maintain efficient operation of systems and equipment; visits and advises clients on the use and servicing of electrical and electronic systems and equipment. 
Other roles: ['Assistant, electronics', 'Engineer, executive (telecommunications)', 'Technician, electronics', 'Officer, signals (MOD)', 'Specialist, telecommunications', 'Technician, electrical', 'Engineer, assistant (broadcasting)', 'Engineer, simulator, flight', 'Technician, telemetry', 'Engineer, testing, cable, assistant', 'Technician, maintenance, electrical', 'Technician', 'Technician, avionics', 'Engineer, installation (electricity supplier)']
```

I have been following: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/02/03/how-to-use-restful-apis-with-django.html and trawled through as much as I can find to help me better understand how to access the list elements and iterate over them.

The template html renders the above:

```
    {% if search_result.success %}
      <p>
        <strong>SOC:</strong> {{ search_result.soc }}
        <br />
        <strong>Title:</strong> {{ search_result.title }}
        <br />
        <strong>Description:</strong> {{ search_result.description }}
        <br />
        <strong>Qualifications:</strong> {{ search_result.qualifications }}
        <br />
        <strong>Tasks:</strong> {{ search_result.tasks }}        
        <br />
        <strong>Other roles:</strong> {{ search_result.add_titles }}
      </p>
    {% else %}
      <p><em>{{ search_result.message }}</em></p>
    {% endif %}
```

Trying to turn the final

```
{{ search_reults.add_titles }}
```

Into a bulleted list, I have tried several different options including:

```
        <ul>
          {% for title in search_result.add_titles %}
              <li>{{ title }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
```

I am hoping to turn the list into something more like this:

- Assistant, electronics
- Engineer, executive (telecommunications)
- Technician, electronics
- Officer, signals (MOD)
- Specialist, telecommunications
- Technician, electrical
- Engineer, assistant (broadcasting)
- Engineer, simulator, flight
- Technician, telemetry
- Engineer, testing, cable, assistant
- Technician, maintenance, electrical
- Technician
- Technician, avionics
- Engineer, installation (electricity supplier)

Any help would be MUCH appreciated - hopefully a novice error?

EDIT:

the current views.py:

```
def lmi4all(request):
    search_result = {}
    if 'SOC' in request.GET:
        soc = request.GET['SOC']
        url = 'http://api.lmiforall.org.uk/api/v1/soc/code/%s' % soc
        response = requests.get(url)
        search_was_successful = (response.status_code == 200)  # 200 = SUCCESS
        search_result = response.json()
        search_result['success'] = search_was_successful

    return render(request, 'core/lmi4all.html', {'search_result': search_result})
```

Comment: What's happening it's that it is taking the other titles list as a whole string, you need to turn it into list first from your view, can you post your view so I can help you ?

Comment: @jsanchezs thanks for having a look - I have added the view - I have tried extracting the `add_titles` specifically but not sure how to return them usably.

Comment: what does `<li>{{ title }}</li>` print?

Comment: @tobyt99 Great, check both answers below and let us know =)

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there!

What you can do is to store the add_titles in a variable from the view(it will create a list that contain every jobs), and then simply add this list in the context.

Then from the template you can use it:

views.py

```
def lmi4all(request):
    search_result = {}
    if 'SOC' in request.GET:
        soc = request.GET['SOC']
        url = 'http://api.lmiforall.org.uk/api/v1/soc/code/%s' % soc
        response = requests.get(url)
        search_was_successful = (response.status_code == 200)  # 200 = SUCCESS
        search_result = response.json()
        other_roles = search_result.get('add_titles')
        search_result['success'] = search_was_successful

    return render(request, 'core/lmi4all.html', {'search_result': search_result, 'other_roles': other_roles})
```

template:

```
{% if search_result.success %}
      <p>
        <strong>SOC:</strong> {{ search_result.soc }}
        <br />
        <strong>Title:</strong> {{ search_result.title }}
        <br />
        <strong>Description:</strong> {{ search_result.description }}
        <br />
        <strong>Qualifications:</strong> {{ search_result.qualifications }}
        <br />
        <strong>Tasks:</strong> {{ search_result.tasks }}        
        <br />
        <strong>Other roles:</strong> 
        <ul>
        {% for role in other_roles %}
          <li>
              {{role}}
          </li>  
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </p>
    {% else %}
      <p><em>{{ search_result.message }}</em></p>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: this almost worked...  THANK YOU.  It turns out that I needed to create the variable `other_roles` before the if statement in views.py - after that, all good.  I think I am confused between [] and () - help much appreciated.

Comment: if you solve the issue because of my answer you can consider upvote or accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that when you use the get function our friend describes earlier, it still takes the field as a whole string, in which case you can solve it with this :

```
roles_list = search_result.get('add_titles').strip(']').strip('[').replace("'", '').split(",")
```

Let us know how it goes.